# How to efficiently map one tensor to another with one-to-multiple relations in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have a tensor `input` and an irregular 2d array `mapping` where `mapping[i]` contains the list of indices of `output` that `input[i]` should be mapped to, how to obtain tensor `output` such that `output[j]` equals to the sum of all the entries in `input` that is mapped to it, without looping? `input` and `output` are of different sizes.

For example:
`input = [0,1,2,3]`
`mapping = [[1], [0,2,4], [0,3], [1,2]]`
`output = [1+2, 0+3, 1+3, 2, 1] = [3,3,4,2,1]`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the [`scatter_add`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_add_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_add_) operation. The trick is to flatten `mapping` and repeat the values of `input` to match `mapping`'s indices layout.

First define the helper tensors `src`, `index`, and `out`:

```
>>> reps = torch.tensor([len(x) for x in mapping])
>>> src = input.repeat_interleave(reps)
tensor([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])

>>> index = torch.tensor([r for x in mapping for r in x])
tensor([1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 3, 1, 2])

>>> out = torch.zeros(max(index)+1, dtype=src.dtype)
tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Applying `scatter_add` on 1D tensors is equivalent to accumulating the following element-wise: `out[index[i]] += src[i]`. So it leaves us with:

```
>>> out.scatter_add(dim=0, index=index, src=src)
tensor([3, 3, 4, 2, 1])
```